# ¿Cómo validar si una clase ya se esta ejecutando?

Tags: java, android-studio

tengo una activity llamada activity_principal y una clase llamada sonidos.class, la clase sonidos la coloque en el onCreate de la activity_principal, para que se active automáticamente cuando se abre la app, funcionan bien.

¿Existe alguna forma de validar si la clase sonidos.class ya se esta ejecutando?, para evitar que se ejecute mas de una vez, lo pregunto porque cuando desde alguna otra activity regreso a la activity_principal, la clase sonidos.class se queda ejecutando 2 veces de forma simultánea (los sonidos que produce la clase sonidos, quedan sonando con eco).

Gracias por las sugerencias

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    Sonidos s = new Sonidos(getApplicationContext());

}
```

Comment: Hola Isabel, me puedes decir si la respuesta dada te fue util, gracias

Comment: Hola Japv, gracias por responder a mi pregunta inicial. El mundo java para mi es algo nuevo, estoy dando mis primeros pasos, tu respuesta la estoy tratando de entender ya que es algo compleja para mi, hay conceptos que no conozco y que debo estudiar. Por lo que analizo en tu respuesta es lo que necesito, voy a tratar de acoplarlo a lo que necesito. Con tu respuesta entiendo que si un proceso se pone en marcha, se asegura para que NO se vuelva a ejecutar. Te pregunto ¿Existe alguna forma de evaluar si ya se esta ejecutando una clase para no volverla a ejecutar? Muchas gracias

Comment: Es lo q te acabo de responder creo que puede servirte, trata de adaptar la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa el **Patrón Singleton**. Este patrón de diseño te garantiza que tu clase solamente se instancie una vez, por ejemplo:

```
class MiClase
{
    private static MiClase miClase = null;

    private MiClase()
    {

    }

    public static MiClase GetMiClase()
    {
        if (miClase != null)
        {
            miClase = new MiClase();
            // Aquí podrías ejecutar tu sonido ya que la clase nunca ha sido instanciada, una vez que se instancie, no se entrará a esta condición.
        }

        return miClase;
    }
}
```

Esta clase implementa el **Patrón Singleton** para asegurar que solamente exista una instancia de la misma. Para ello se declara una **variable privada** del mismo tipo de la clase y para evitar que el constructor sea invocado se hace privado, al hacer el **constructor privado** ya no podemos hacer el siguiente código desde fuera de la clase:

```
MiClase clase = new MiClase();
```

Pero de alguna forma debemos crearla es aquí donde construimos el objeto mediante un **método estático**:

```
public static MiClase GetMiClase()
{
   if (miClase != null)
   {
      miClase = new MiClase();
      // Aquí podrías ejecutar tu sonido ya que la clase nunca ha sido instanciada, una vez que se instancie, no se entrará a esta condición.
   }

   return miClase;
}
```

Aquí se pregunta si la **variable privada miClase es nula**, de serlo quiere decir que dicha clase nunca ha sido instanciada, por tanto se construye. De no ser nula pues no se se hace nada ya que el objeto fue creado previamente, en ambos casos se retorna a la **variable miClase**.

Para usar este patrón haríamos en tu código:

```
MiClase miClase = MiClase.GetMiClase();
```

Revisa bien todo lo que te explico y busca más información sobre este patrón de diseño en Internet.